# Tkinter error 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter, lista

Necesito realizar un programa que pida un numero "Numero de generadores" y al darle el botón de "aceptar", se cree un lista con el numero de espacios igual al ingresado, ademas de crear una matriz de 0 de la dimensión antes mencionada, hasta ahí todo funciona

Ahora necesito que cuando se ingrese los valores en la lista y darle en "Calcular" estos valores reemplacen a los valores de la diagonal de la matriz, intente utilizar un for para que lea numero por numero en la lista y lo reemplaze en la matriz, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/matrices.py", line 87, in BaseD
>     matriz_v[(i),(i)]=Barras[i].get()
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
> ```

y no se como solucionar el problema, espero me puedan ayudar

```
import numpy
from tkinter import *

#crear las tablas   
def Tabla():

    def BaseD():
        global matriz_v

        for i in range(0,m):
            matriz_v[(i),(i)]=Barras[i].get()   
        print(matriz_v)    


    m = n_generadores.get()
    matriz_v = numpy.zeros((m,m))
    print(matriz_v)
    #TABLAS
    ventData.geometry("1500x600+0+0")
    lbld_generadores=Label(ventData,text="Datos de los generadores: ",font=(14)).grid(row=4,column=0)

    #NUMERO DE LA BARRA DONDE SE UBICARA EL GENERADOR
    n_Barra=["Barra"]
    #Creacion de la fila de etiquetas BARRA
    for i in range(len(n_Barra)):
        Label(ventData,text=n_Barra[i],bg="LightSteelBlue2",font=(12),relief=GROOVE,padx=10,pady=5).grid(row=4,column=i+1)
    #crear las filas de acuerdo al numero de barras ingresadas
    filasB=n_generadores.get()
    Barras=[]
    for i in range(filasB):
        Barras.append([0]*len(n_Barra))
        for j in range(len(n_Barra)):
            Barras[i][j]=("B"+str(i)+str(j))
            Barras[i][j]=DoubleVar()
            Entry(ventData,textvariable=Barras[i][j],width=16,bg="beige").grid(row=i+5,column=j+1)


#CALCULAR
    btnCreaBD=Button(ventData,text="Calcular",font=(14),command=BaseD,padx=10,pady=1).grid(row=filasB+7,column=1)
    lblVacia=Label(ventData,text="").grid(row=filasB+8,column=2)

#Ventana inicial
ventData=Tk()
ventData.geometry("800x400+0+0")
ventData.title("DESPACHO ECONOMICO")

lbln_generadores=Label(ventData,text="Número de Generadores: ",font=(16)).grid(row=1,column=0)

#Parametro de entrada - numero de generadores
n_generadores=IntVar()

txtBarras=Entry(ventData,textvariable=n_generadores).grid(row=2,column=0)

#Boton Aceptar
btnn_generadores=Button(ventData,text="Aceptar",font=(14),command=Tabla,padx=10,pady=1).grid(row=2,column=1)

#Insertar fila vacia
lblVacia=Label(ventData,text="").grid(row=2,column=2)

ventData.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes bastantes problemas en el código:

- El error salta porque `Barras` es una lista de dos dimensiones, `Barras[i]` retorna una lista anidada, no una de las variables de Tkinter que hay dentro de ella.
- Por otro lado, no puedes definir la función `BaseD` dentro de la función `Tabla` si pretendes llamarla al pulsar el botón. Esta función tiene una vida muy corta, se crea cuando se llama a `Tabla` y cuando `Tabla` retorna `BaseD` deja de existir, por lo que no la puedes llamar posteriormente.
- Además, necesitarás que `Tablas` sea una variable global para acceder a ella desde las dos funciones.

Aparte de esto, dos apuntes:

- Usar `from módulo import *` para importar es una **mala práctica** que debe evitarse siempre. No uses `from tkinter import *`, usa `import tkinter`, `import tkinter as tk` o `from tkinter import Button, Label....`
- Si das un nombre a una instancia de un widget (botón, label, etc) se supone que es para usar ese nombre para acceder a propiedades del widget. En este caso separa el método `pack`, `grid`, etc de la instacia. Si haces:

  ```
  txtBarras=Entry(ventData,textvariable=n_generadores).grid(row=2,column=0)
  ```

  `txtBarras` no es una instancia de `Entry` sino que es `None`, el retorno del método `grid`. Esto hace que, lógicamente, no puedas acceder al `Entry` ni a sus propiedades, por ejemplo `txtBarras.get()` dará error. Por esos debes hacer:

  ```
  txtBarras=Entry(ventData,textvariable=n_generadores)
  txtBarras.grid(row=2,column=0)
  ```

  Si no vas a necesitar acceder a la instancia entonces no  crees un montón de variables que van a contener todas `None`, simplemente haces:

  ```
  Entry(ventData,textvariable=n_generadores).grid(row=2,column=0)
  ```

El código funcional quedaría así:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk


matriz_v = None
Barras = []


def BaseD():
    #Es necesario usar global si vas a usar matriz_v fuera de esta funcion
    global  matriz_v

    m = n_generadores.get()
    matriz_v = np.zeros((m,m))

    for i in range(0,m):
        matriz_v[i,i] = Barras[i][0].get()   
    print(matriz_v)  

#crear las tablas   
def Tabla():

    #TABLAS
    ventData.geometry("1500x600+0+0")
    lbld_generadores = tk.Label(ventData, text="Datos de los generadores: ", font=14)
    lbld_generadores.grid(row=4, column=0)

    #NUMERO DE LA BARRA DONDE SE UBICARA EL GENERADOR
    n_Barra = ["Barra"]
    #Creacion de la fila de etiquetas BARRA
    for i in range(len(n_Barra)):
        tk.Label(ventData, text=n_Barra[i], bg="LightSteelBlue2", font=(12), relief=tk.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=5).grid(row=4,column=i+1)

    #crear las filas de acuerdo al numero de barras ingresadas
    filasB = n_generadores.get()

    for i in range(filasB):
        Barras.append([0]*len(n_Barra))
        for j in range(len(n_Barra)):
            Barras[i][j]=("B{}{}".format(i, j))
            Barras[i][j] = tk.DoubleVar()
            tk.Entry(ventData, textvariable=Barras[i][j], width=16, bg="beige").grid(row=i+5, column=j+1)


#CALCULAR
    btnCreaBD = tk.Button(ventData,text="Calcular",font=(14),command=BaseD,padx=10,pady=1)
    btnCreaBD.grid(row=filasB+7,column=1)
    lblVacia = tk.Label(ventData,text="")
    lblVacia.grid(row=filasB+8,column=2)

#Ventana inicial
ventData=tk.Tk()
ventData.geometry("800x400+0+0")
ventData.title("DESPACHO ECONOMICO")

lbln_generadores=tk.Label(ventData,text="Número de Generadores: ",font=(16))
lbln_generadores.grid(row=1,column=0)

#Parametro de entrada - numero de generadores
n_generadores=tk.IntVar()

txtBarras=tk.Entry(ventData,textvariable=n_generadores)
txtBarras.grid(row=2,column=0)

#Boton Aceptar
btnn_generadores=tk.Button(ventData,text="Aceptar",font=(14),command=Tabla,padx=10,pady=1)
btnn_generadores.grid(row=2,column=1)

#Insertar fila vacia
lblVacia=tk.Label(ventData,text="")
lblVacia.grid(row=2,column=2)

ventData.mainloop()
```

Observa que no es necesario usar `global` cuando lo que se hace es modificar objetos mutables como listas o arrays de NumPy. Si sobreescribieras la variable con otro objeto o este fuera inmutable (`int`, `float`, `str`, etc) si necesitas usar `global`.

No obstante te recomendaría usar programación orientada a objetos (clases). Te evitas usar **variables globales** (las cuales **hay que evitar en lo posible**), el código estará mucho más organizado, al final tendrás que escribir menos código, y sobre todo la Gui será mucho más flexible, extensible y reutilizable.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es tomar el elemento que se encuentra en cierta posición de la lista, basta con hacer `lista[indice]`.
Las listas no tienen el atributo `get()`, esos son los diccionarios si no me equivoco.